# Cannot resolve symbol (variables)

Tags: java, android, json

I am very new to Android, it would be great if you could help me with the error "Cannot resolve symbol ..." in the variables:

- value 1

- banner_id

- full_id

My code is the following:

```
package com.example.sienstranslation.siensapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.appdatasearch.GetRecentContextCall;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        double precio = intent.getExtras().getDouble("precio");
        String precio_rounded = String.format("%.2f", precio);
        TextView txtCambio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txtCambio.setText("Precio Total: "+ precio_rounded + " €");
    }

    void MakePostRequest() {
        String posting_url ="http://ipaddress/app.php";
        // its your url path ok
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, posting_url ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            value1= jsonResponse.getString("precio_rounded");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            banner_id = null;
                            full_id = null;
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        value1= null;
                    }
                }
        ) {
            // here is params will add to your url using post method
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("app", getString(R.string.app_name));
                //params.put("2ndParamName","valueoF2ndParam");
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
    }
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: clean-rebuild first

Comment: Post the logcat and also mention the line at which you are getting the error.

Comment: Did you declare them ?

Comment: declare `banner_id`

Comment: Use data type banner_id = null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first , Declare  `banner_id` & `full_id` ;

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int banner_id,full_id;
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild** Your Project .

Comment: Thank you. Now, banner_id and full_id are incompatible types (required int, found null). 
I also changed this: value1= jsonResponse.getString("precio_rounded"); to this: value1= jsonResponse.getInt("precio_rounded"); 
Is that OK a "getInt" if I am trying to get a double?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad idea to start directly with Android ... when you don't have **any** clue about java itself. In your program, you are **using** those three variables without ever **declaring** them before. That is what the compiler is telling you. That is **super basic** stuff.

So I seriously recommend you to step back; and study those java basics for some more time. Otherwise your programming experience will be nothing else but a (probably short) series of very frustrating moments.

This is not meant to be rude; but it looks like you intend to build a skyscraper; but you actually have no idea how to dig the hole for the basement. That is simply not a very rewarding or efficient approach to get things done.

And you see, your follow-on comments to the answers ... just prove my point. Your current approach is nothing but trial-and-error. And just to be precise: the Android java programming model is itself something that can drive experienced java programmers nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare all variables before they can be used. The basic form of a variable declaration is shown here:

data type variable [ = value][, variable [= value] ...] ;

Comment: Bad idea. He is a newbie; worst case he will be copying your statements directly, and that really wont help; besides the assignment with null is neither required; nor actually helpful.

Comment: It's OK, data type are string, int, etc.